# iterate over cluster in markerCluster : leaflet

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers

i need to iterate over all clusters that are currently present in markercluster using leaflet. there's a method called **markercluster.getClusters() in googlemaps** to do this job.

is there something similar in leaflet too?

Comment: pls help..it's urgent!!

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @toms answer

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){     //iterate over map rather than clusters
 if (layer.getChildCount){         // if layer is markerCluster
  console.log(layer._childCount);  // return count of points within each cluster
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if you mean iterate over all the individual points in an `L.markerClusterGroup()`, you can use something like this to access the individual layers

```
markers.eachLayer(function(layer){
  console.log(layer)
});
```

If you want to get at the points/layers in an individual cluster, you can use `getAllChildMarkers()`

```
markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    console.log('cluster ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});
```

additional documentation **[here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)**

Comment: hey thanks for your early reply..i want to iterate over clusters not over markers in the markercluster.eg: if say suppose currently i can see 2 clusters on the screen, then i want to retive those two individual clusters. refer getClusters() method in google maps